how to fix height of scrollbar track
Need to fix the height of the scrollbar track and it should be starting with that blue colour only and the background should be of grey colour can you please guide me with the implementation.
I tried implementing without fixing the height and background colour as transparent.



Actual
Expected










do yourself a favour: https://codepen.io/stephenpaton-tech/full/JjRvGmY | https://www.cssportal.com/css-scrollbar-generator/ | https://webkit-scroll-gen.sourceforge.net/ | https://scrollbar.app/ etcetera

You could use ::-webkit-scrollbar :
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 35%, 0.1);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #007;
}



I want my scrollbar to be starting from middle of the page
